# LaPlace Derivative Thereom

Tags: laplace-transform

No idea what this is saying...

The real part (or is it the magnitude of the complex f(t)) is less than Me^{yt}. Why is y any real number, and not restricted to say > 0.

Then 1.3, taking the laplace transform of the function derivative. Why is (s) outside? Shouldn't it be written L(f'(s))?

[image]

Fairly stumped at what this is trying to tell me

Comment: Use the definition of the laplace transform for f’ then use integration by parts.

Comment: It says the Laplace transform behaves nicely under differentiation, which is a consequence of integration by parts and $(e^{-st})' = -s e^{-st}$

Answer (score 0):

Write (1.3) as
$L(f')(s)
=sL(f)(s)-f(0)
$.

Putting
$f'$ for $f$,
this becomes
$L(f'')(s)
=sL(f')(s)-f'(0)
$.

Putting
(1.3) in this,
we get
$L(f'')(s)
=s(sL(f)(s)-f(0))-f'(0)
=s^2L(f)(s)-sf(0)-f'(0)
$.

By induction,
we can get
a formula for
$L(f^{(n)})(s)
$.